# Visual Studio 2015 and VB Macros

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vbscript, macros

I have VS2015 with installed VSMacros.vsix (Macros for Visual Studio) and also Vb61.VbTools.vsix (Visual Basic extension).
When I open Macro Explorer I can record, and edit macros but they are written in java script. I have older project and need to port it to VS2015. This project uses VBScript macros. I cannot find information if VSMacros.vsix extension also support VBScript macros. In this project VBMacros are used in Pre and Post-build events. Is possible to use VBMacros in VS2015 or not ?

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned in [the FAQ for the extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-Macros).  **No**.